# power bi: how to rotate vertically column names in matrix

Tags: powerbi

Would you help me, please, to rotate vertically column names in matrix in power bi like in the attached picture.

Thank you.

[image: example]

Comment: Matrix/Table visual doesn't support that sort of formatting

Comment: Jon, thank you. I anticipated this since there is no information about it in forums. May be, there is some way to do it with outside plugins?

Comment: Unfortunately that feature is not supported. Check this link for a possible workaround. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/vertical-headers-in-table/m-p/788362